# Instancia de métodos en Java con validación de datos

Tags: java

`- Hola, estoy practicando Java luego de algunos meses.
Esta es una calculadora simple que estoy haciendo,
funciona bien las validaciones
pero la captura de los números
no pasa
las funciones correctas.
Se trata de una simple calculadora, la cual debe aceptar números tipo double, hasta el momento funciona bien la validacion, pero además debe realizar la operatoria correctamente. Para que el IDE no tirara errores repetí varias veces los parámetros, lógicamente esto no se hace así pero era para ver si compilaba o no.

Se me hace la confusión en la sintaxis correcta de la instanciacion de clases en lo que respecta a una funcion para no tener que escribirla en el main.

Nota importante, las validaciones las hice a partir de código sacado de otros websites, por ejemplo el trycatch y el casebreak.

```
 Este es mi código:
   Antemano, no tira errores, pero solamente captura datos y no los opera.
   ¿Qué está errado?
   Gracias 


  
`
```

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Calculadora {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double primerOperando = 0;
            double segundoOperando = 0;
            boolean datosCorrectos = false;
            char operador = 0;
            double resultado = 0;
            int intentar = 0;
    capturaInput( primerOperando, segundoOperando, datosCorrectos);
    escogeOperacion(primerOperando, segundoOperando, operador);
    mostrarResultado(primerOperando, segundoOperando, resultado, operador);
    
    
        }
    
        public static boolean capturaInput(double primerOperando, double segundoOperando, boolean datosCorrectos) {
            Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                System.out.println("Ingrese primer número");
                primerOperando = lector.nextDouble();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Favor solo números");
            }
    
            try {
                System.out.println("Ingresar segundo número");
                segundoOperando = lector.nextDouble();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Nuevamente favor solo números");
            }
    
    
    
            return datosCorrectos = true;
    }
    public static double escogeOperacion(double primerOperando, double segundoOperando,  double resultado){
        System.out.print("Ingrese un operador (+. -, *, /): ");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operador = lector.next().charAt(0);
        switch(operador)
        {
            case '+':
                resultado = primerOperando + segundoOperando;
                break;
            case '-':
                resultado = primerOperando - segundoOperando;
                break;
            case '*':
                resultado = primerOperando * segundoOperando;
                break;
            case '/':
                resultado = primerOperando / segundoOperando;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error, el operador no corresponde");
                return resultado;
    
        }
            return resultado;
    
    }
    public static double mostrarResultado(double resultado, double primerOperando, double segundoOperando, char operador){
        System.out.println(primerOperando + " " + operador + " " + segundoOperando + " = " + resultado);
        return resultado;
    }
    
    }
```

```
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos detalles tu código.

1. Usas variables locales que solo son afectados en el método donde se usa y no se setea el valor para que se use en los otros métodos. Ejemplo:

   ```
           import java.util.Scanner;
           public class Calculadora {
             public static void main(String[] args) {
                double primerOperando = 0;  //variable
                double segundoOperando = 0; //variable
                boolean datosCorrectos = false; //variable
                char operador = 0;   //Variable
                double resultado = 0; //variable
                int intentar = 0;
                capturaInput( primerOperando, segundoOperando, datosCorrectos); 
                escogeOperacion(primerOperando, segundoOperando, operador);
                mostrarResultado(primerOperando, segundoOperando, resultado, operador);
   ```

En el código anterior vemos las variables primerOperando, segundoOperando, operador que se están usando en métodos separados, solo sufren cambio en el metodo usado y no se está llevando los valores hacia los otros métodos, es decir en el método **capturaInput** se usan y se asigna pero en ningun momento estos valores se pasan al otro método de **escogeOperacion**, esto quiere decir que aqui llegarian en **0**.

2. En el siguiente código, estas repitiendo los try/catch

   ```
           try {
               System.out.println("Ingrese primer número");
               primerOperando = lector.nextDouble();
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Favor solo números");
           }

           try {
               System.out.println("Ingresar segundo número");
               segundoOperando = lector.nextDouble();
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Nuevamente favor solo números");
           }
   ```
3. En la firma del método **mostrarResultado** tienes *double resultado, double primerOperando, double segundoOperando, char operador*  pero en donde se llama este método se está mandando diferente los parámetros.

   ```
         mostrarResultado(primerOperando, segundoOperando, resultado, operador);
   ```

Te dejo el código mejorado, fijate bien cada línea.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculadora {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result=true;
        while(result) { //ponemos un while para que cada que exista un error vuelva a inicializar 
            result=capturaInput();//Ya no es necesario mandar los parametros ya que se han declado dentro del metodo
        }
    }

    public static boolean capturaInput() {
        double primerOperando=0; 
        double segundoOperando=0;
        double resultado = 0;
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                System.out.println("Ingrese primer número");
                primerOperando = lector.nextDouble();   
                
                System.out.println("Ingresar segundo número");
                segundoOperando = lector.nextDouble();
                
                escogeOperacion(primerOperando, segundoOperando, resultado); //Este método se ha puesto aqui para que las valores recuperados de primeroOperando y segundoOoperando no se pierdan
                return false;//Si todo fue exitoso retorna un false para que no siga ciclando
            }catch(Exception e){ //Se ha quidado un try/catch
                System.out.println("Nuevamente favor solo números");
            }           
       return true; //Si tuviese un error caería en true para que se inicialice de nuevo el metodo para ingresar los numeros.
}

public static void escogeOperacion(double primerOperando, double segundoOperando,  double resultado){
    System.out.print("Ingrese un operador (+. -, *, /): ");
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    char operador = lector.nextLine().charAt(0);
    switch(operador)
    {
        case '+':
            resultado = primerOperando
            + segundoOperando;
            break;
        case '-':
            resultado = primerOperando - segundoOperando;
            break;
        case '*':
            resultado = primerOperando * segundoOperando;
            break;
        case '/':
            resultado = primerOperando / segundoOperando;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error, el operador no corresponde");
            break;
    }
        mostrarResultado(primerOperando, segundoOperando, resultado, operador); //Se ha puesto aqui este método para que los valores de primerOperando y segundoOperando no se pierdan
}

public static double mostrarResultado( double primerOperando, double segundoOperando, double resultado,char operador){
    System.out.println(primerOperando + " " + operador + " " + segundoOperando + " = " + resultado);
    return resultado;
}

}
```